# Chance calculation question

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A bus has $4$ passengers the bus goes over a trajectory of $10$ bus stops. There is a $\frac{1}{10}$ chance that a passenger exits the bus at a stop. What is the chance that all passengers exit the bus at different stops?

I thought maybe make a chance tree for this question but the tree would be too large. Can someone help me?

Comment: There are $10\times 9 \times 8\times 7$ ways for four (different) passengers to get off at four different stops (out of a possible ten).  How many unrestricted ways are there?

Comment: I am sorry I don't understand the question. If you qre talking about how many ways they can get off in terms of the order then I would say order doesn't matter.

Comment: How many ways can the four distinct passengers get off if you don't care whether two or more get off at the same stop?

Comment: @lulu 210 I think

Comment: How did you get that number?

Comment: @lulu  combinations of 4 out of 10

Comment: No...I asked you about the unrestricted case.  When you do not care if two or more get off at the same stop.  Your calculation sort of handles the restricted case, though you still have to multiply by $4!$ to account for the different passengers.

Comment: To get a probability in problems like this you have to count all the ways to do it, then count the good ways to do it and then the answer is the ratio of the number of good ways to the total number of ways. at least assuming that each way to do it is equally probable.

Comment: @lulu 10000 then ? as in 10^4?

Comment: Absolutely.  Do you see why the number of good ways is $4!\times \binom {10}4$?

Comment: @lulu You mean 4!*210 right?

Comment: Yes.  $\binom nk$ is a fairly standard notation for the number of ways to choose $k$  objects out of a possible $n$.  This is the same value as I wrote out in my initial comment.

Comment: @lulu ohw wow thank you I just realized those are the same thanks

Comment: No problem.  Good luck.